# Upgrading to CDT 8.1.2 results in semantic errors on #include

Tags: eclipse, android-ndk, eclipse-cdt

I tried upgrading to CDT 8.1.2 and am getting semantic errors on things like `#include <jni.h>` and `#include <string.h>` in the syntax check pre-processor, but the program still compiles fine. I tried unchecking `[ ] Allow heuristic resolution of include`. The paths still seem correct.

Thankfully I made a backup copy of my Eclipse directory and project before upgrading.

Whatever is happening, the new version of the CDT appears to change the workspace, so by reverting eclipse to the prior version, the effected workspace is still effected. The only way I've found to fix it is to revert both eclipse and the workspace.

I've got some work to get done, but latter tonight I hope to try walking the upgrade in piece by piece and try to determine what component was causing the problem.

Anyone else seeing this?  Found a solution?

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but on a standard desktop Qt application. My workspace consists of multiple C++ projects - which are all identically configured with respect to project settings and include paths. After the update to CDT 8.1.2 the Eclipse indexer in one of my projects cannot find ANY of the Qt include files and consequently there are a ton of resolution errors. This is not Android specific. I've tried to find a solution the whole day, and nothing has worked so far. It is especially frustrating since all other projects are indexed just fine.